# Starting a background application automatically on boot

Tags: boot, autostart, startup-applications

I can run the following command in a terminal

```
sudo /usr/sbin/archttp64 81
```

which is a management console for the RAID controller on this machine.  Then I can run Firefox and use the address: `localhost:81` and log into the console and manage my RAID set.

I don't want to have to do this every time I want to check in on my RAID set, plus, unless the utility is running I won't receive status emails if there is an issue.

I've tried using the "**Startup Applications**" and add an Additional Startup Program, but its not working properly or more likely I've got something mis-configured.

My info in Edit Startup Program:

- Name: Areca ArcHTTP Utility
- Command: /usr/sbin/archttp64 81
- Comment:

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the following links:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/07/adding-a-startup-script-to-be-run-at-bootup

Comment: Thanks Green7. Got it working using your hint. Here is what I did:

Open Terminal

Cd /etc/init.d

sudo nano

added:  /usr/sbin/archttp64 81

saved file as archttpstart

sudo update-rc.d archttpstart defaults

sudo chmod +x archttpstart

Rebooted machine and tested (It Worked!)

YAY!! Thanks Again.

Comment: Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Any script that you place in **/etc/rc.local** file will execute on boot.

Place your command there without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work?

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/archttp64 81
```

Put the script in, for example, /usr/local/bin/MyScript.sh

If you have the desktop version, just click on the `Shutdown icon` to the top right and add the script to `startup applications`. If not, take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1767979)